# How to create a table with a single border using bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a simple bordered table using bootstrap 3 but I haven't found a good way to get the right-border to show other than something hacky like this

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover sch-cust-tbl">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="border-right-color: #ddd;">foo</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my custom css to get the hover working (mostly)

```
.table-bordered tbody tr td:first-child
{                                                                                               border-right-color: white; 
}                                                                                           
.table-bordered thead tr th:first-child    
{                                                                                               border-right-color: white;  
}
```

What I'd love to see is a table with no inner borders but the entire outside is bordered (plus a top and bottom border for each row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest things are often the best :

```
<table class="table table-hover sch-cust-tbl">
    ...
</table>
```

```
.sch-cust-tbl {
    border: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/103481)**

[image]